# iMacros-like program that can run from the command line to automate browser actions?

Tags: unix, browser, selenium, imacros

Here's what I would like to do:

Cron execute an iMacro (or iMacro-like) script on a headless unix server - essentially doing my browser interactions for me.

Is this possible?

I'm sure cURL won't be able to traverse the DOM and trigger user events. iMacros would be perfect if I could run it in unix CLI, which you can, but I run a headless server without Xorg and obviously FF requires Xorg. iMacro with Lynx would be good but I doubt iMacro works with Lynx.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I was looking for about the same thing, and I found this post on Google. Here the answser :

There is some headless browser which can run on an Unix system without Xorg. You can try CasperJS, PhantomJS or Zombie by example.